# Running IntelliTrace on a box without Visual Studio on a Managed Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, intellitrace

I keep getting the same error when attempting to run IntelliTrace on a Managed Windows Service under a 64 bit installation of Windows 7

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.239 - Loading profiler failed during
>   CoCreateInstance.  Profiler CLSID:
>   '{301EC75B-AD5A-459C-A4C4-911C878FA196}'.  HRESULT: 0x800700c1. 
>   Process ID (decimal): 3772.  Message ID: [0x2504].

The article that I referenced as the source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msaffer/archive/2011/02/23/using-intellitrace-with-services.aspx

Has anyone attempted this with much success?

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN blog post you referenced assumes you have VS 2010 installed on the box. Intellitrace is not supported without VS 2010. In fact, the CLSID in your error message points to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools\TraceLogProfiler.dll", which is apparently part of VS intallation.

There is another blog post [here](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/04/28/useintellitracewithoutvsnet/) that claims to have solved the problem. You can try that.

Comment: I have tried that solution too. Thanks for the response though